# XCode project is poisoned, can't add any new elements to storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-storyboard

I was using XCode 7 Beta 5 and my project's storyboard stopped letting me add any elements to it. (I added a new view controller to the storyboard and was trying to set up a popover segue right before it crapped itself, but I don't think this is very related or helpful to know). So I did all these steps https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Fixing-Xcode (clean project, clean project folders, delete caches, reset all settings, etc), ran some guy's "Fix XCode" script (https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vineetchoudhary/b09c3f40ca29d36c8863/raw/e79bd67b81202e62a750731c80378d25f1001ace/fix-xcode.rb), updated to the latest XCode 7.3.1 and rebooted a few times.

So yeah, it's still broken (can't add any new ui elements), I make a backup and start deleting things. The new view controller I added I deleted, I deleted another possibly related view controller, it's still not letting me add anything to the remaining view controllers in the storyboard. All my constraints are fine, I tried letting them auto align as well as manually aligning them (which I had been doing successfully right before XCode decided it was done working forever)

I'm not using any xibs or objective C, the entire project is Swift 2 and a couple Storyboards.

so

---

### Expected behavior:

Can drag objects from Object Library (such as text, switch, button, etc) into storyboard to create UI

### Actual behavior:

Objects from object library can be added to storyboard, aligned, and saved, but when running in simulator, they do not appear. Existing ui elements can be deleted (reflected in simulator), code changes can still be made, but new UI elements just can't be added.

---

At this point I'm probably going to have to recreate the whole project. I'm considering the project "poisoned" and I'm considering XCode BS. If anyone knows anything let me know

Comment: In all my years of making iOS app this will be the first - project is "poisoned". You can always create & add a new storyboard file and add it to your project ... assuming storyboard is the only issue here.

Comment: Are you certain you're adding the objects to AnyHeight and AnyWidth and you're not just sabotaging yourself with size-classes?

Comment: Also, at this point, why would you be using a beta of Xcode 7?  Get the release version, which has been out for 9 months.  The current release is 7.3.1 and it's a free download from the Mac App Store.

Comment: You got me Dare. Thanks very very much, and I am very very dumb. It was in compact x compact which I thought was fine for testing on iphone 4s, but apparently it's compact x regular.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issues after I used the autolayout feature.

Close your current XCode project and then reopen your project.
After that you will be able to add new objects to your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using cocapods and working via workspace. Try to open the project file NOT workspace file and try to edit your storyboard there.